# Test accuracy is lower than the validate accuracy in classification

Tags: classification, cross-validation

I separated my data set into three parts includes training, validate, and testing. I performed k-fold validation with using the validate set, then test the true performance of the predictive model using the test set.

However, I could see that the classification accuracy using the test(unseen data) is pretty low. (~15% lower than the validation accuracy.) Is this normal? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is natural. Cross-validation almost always lead to lower estimated errors - it uses some data that are different from test set so it will cause overfitting for sure. But the percentage of decrease is quite big, and if you have big sample size and it can not be explained with stochastic effects, I would suggest that your classification method is overcomplicated.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I have got a multiclass classification problem (3 classes) where there is no many significant features related to the target. I ended up having around 55% accuracy rate for my best model. My test accuracy reveals ~38%. I split 60/20/20.

Comment: @Rapry But how many samples do you have?

Comment: I have 4,000 samples which is large enough (the optimal one).

Comment: by the way, and selected model is not overtrainning.

Comment: @Rapry try to choose not the best model (according to cross-validation), but the model with sub-optimal CV performance and less number of estimated parameters. Is your split completely random? How did you understand that selected model was not overtrained? I guess such decrease of performance directly indicate overtraining by definition.

Comment: I put a condition check that mean of validation from k-fold is not over the mean of training. My split method is based on hold-out.

Comment: Thanks. I will check the model with sub-optimal and see the results.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, it does not mean that you did not overtrain your model. You trained it on training set, then tested several models on validation dataset (using CV) and chosen **the best one** from several. Simply, you can overtrain on your validation dataset, not necessarily on training.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I did. Some of my model, the validation accuracy is higher than the train one. However, I am still suffering from low test accuracy.

Comment: As said by others,  this may be exactly expected based on what you did due to overfitting.

Comment: German, as it is I cannot agree with "Cross-validation almost always lead to lower estimated errors": if done properly, CV typically has a pessimistic rather than an optimistic bias. However, double-use of test results such as using the CV for selection *and* for estimating the selected model's generalization error is one of the typical mistakes that lead to optimistic bias: the selection is part of the training of the final model; the cv-test sets are not independent of the model.

Comment: @cbeleites you choose the best model on the current dataset, i.e., fits better on the current validation dataset, so it is "most suited for current dataset with all of the noise inside". I guess it clearly leads to optimistic bias. How negative bias can be arised?

Comment: Sure, but the optimistic bias is not connected to the method for measuring performance - it arises with CV, hold out, independent test sets, .... The optimistic bias is caused by the data-driven selection process which makes the test set used for model selection part of the *training* of the final model. Pessimistic bias of cross validation with proper (= truly independent) splitting is usually attributed to a rising learning curve: The performance of a model trained on the whole data set is approximated by CV error, but the CV surrogate model was trained on fewer cases, and is thus worse.

Comment: @cbeleites I guess here the data is divided to test/train/validaiton datasets so this issue should not arise. I found this paper and suggest that it shows positive bias even after adjustment (http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/papers/cvbias.pdf), but the paper is quite new. Still can not understand how negative bias can arise...I guess the splitting was completely random in the paper.